# Why does Android crash when I uninstall my Appcelerator application with module?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've created a module for Titanium to send data from my app to my Android Wear application which works great. But when I uninstall the application Android crashes. I've checked Logcat but I don't see what the problem exactly is. Android only seems to crash if I uninstall the application right after calling module.sendData() (see example)

- Titanium SDK: 5.3.0
- Android: 6.0.1
- Phone: Samsung Galaxy s6

Example:

index.js (app)

```
function onOpen() {
  var module = require('teunozz.test.module')

  module.addEventListener('connected', function f() {
    console.log('send data');
    module.sendData();
  });

  module.start();
}

$.index.open();
```

index.xml (app)

```
<Alloy>
  <Window id="index" onOpen="onOpen">
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

AndroidWearClient (module)

```
package teunozz.test.module;

import org.appcelerator.titanium.TiApplication;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiActivityResultHandler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataMapRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

public class AndroidWearClient extends Object implements    
    TiActivityResultHandler,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{
    private final static String TAG = "AndroidWearClient";

    private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;
    private GoogleApiClient client = null;
    private TitestModule module = null;
    private boolean authInProgress = false;

    private void buildClient() {
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(
                TiApplication.getAppCurrentActivity())
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    public void start(TitestModule moduleArg) {
        module = moduleArg;
        buildClient();
        client.connect();
    }

    public void stop() {
    }

    public void onError(Activity activity, int requestCode, Exception e) {
    }

    public void onResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
            authInProgress = false;
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (!client.isConnecting() && !client.isConnected()) {
                    client.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    }

    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // connected to Google Wearable API
        module.fireEvent("connected", null);
    }

    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    }

    public void sendData() {
        // Construct a DataRequest and send over the data layer
        PutDataMapRequest putDMR = PutDataMapRequest.create("/test");
        putDMR.getDataMap().putString("key", "test");
        PutDataRequest request = putDMR.asPutDataRequest();
        DataApi.DataItemResult result = 
        // this is the problematic bit if you comment this out  Android doesn't crash
        Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(client, request).await();

        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            // Do something
            Log.e(TAG, "SUCCESS");
        } else {
            // Do something
        }
    }    
}
```

TitestModule (module)

```
package teunozz.test.module;

import teunozz.test.module.AndroidWearClient;

import org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollDict;
import org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollModule;
import org.appcelerator.kroll.annotations.Kroll;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.TiApplication;
import org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiIntentWrapper;
import org.appcelerator.kroll.common.Log;
import org.appcelerator.kroll.common.TiConfig;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;


@Kroll.module(name="Titest", id="teunozz.test.module")
public class TitestModule extends KrollModule
{

    // Standard Debugging variables
    private static final String LCAT = "TitestModule";
    private static final boolean DBG = TiConfig.LOGD;

    private AndroidWearClient client = new AndroidWearClient();

    // You can define constants with @Kroll.constant, for example:
    // @Kroll.constant public static final String EXTERNAL_NAME = value;

    public TitestModule()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Kroll.onAppCreate
    public static void onAppCreate(TiApplication app)
    {
        // put module init code that needs to run when the application is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(Activity activity) {  
        client.stop();
    }

    @Kroll.method
    public void start() {

        TiApplication appContext = TiApplication.getInstance();
        Activity activity = appContext.getCurrentActivity();

        client.start(this);
    }

    @Kroll.method
    public void stop() {
        client.stop();
    }

    @Kroll.method
    public void sendData() {
        client.sendData();
    }
}
```

The basic module code and distribution is available on GitHub: https://github.com/Teunozz/titest

**Update Logcat output**

This is the first error that I can find.

```
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: NetworkPolicy
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_TEMP_WHITELIST_CHANGED flg=0x40000010 bqHint=4 } in com.android.server.net.NetworkPolicyManagerService$4@bd55cc8
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1003)
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at com.android.server.net.NetworkPolicyManagerService.isUidIdle(NetworkPolicyManagerService.java:3471)
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at com.android.server.net.NetworkPolicyManagerService.updateRuleForAppIdleLocked(NetworkPolicyManagerService.java:3397)
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at com.android.server.net.NetworkPolicyManagerService.updateRulesForTempWhitelistChangeLocked(NetworkPolicyManagerService.java:3451)
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at com.android.server.net.NetworkPolicyManagerService$4.onReceive(NetworkPolicyManagerService.java:731)
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:993)
06-20 13:36:06.599: E/AndroidRuntime(14455):    ... 4 more
06-20 13:36:06.659: E/android.os.Debug(14455): ro.product_ship = true
06-20 13:36:06.659: E/android.os.Debug(14455): ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
06-20 13:36:06.659: E/android.os.Debug(14455): sys.mobilecare.preload = false
...
```

After this every service dies and Android restarts.

```
06-20 13:36:07.049: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'wifip2p' died
06-20 13:36:07.059: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'package' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'user' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'activity' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'procstats' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'meminfo' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'gfxinfo' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'dbinfo' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'cpuinfo' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'permission' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'processinfo' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'sensorservice' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'lock_settings' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'mdm.remotedesktop' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'battery' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'usagestats' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'webviewupdate' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'scheduling_policy' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'telephony.registry' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'persona' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'deviceidle' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'application_policy' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'wifi_policy' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'phone_restriction_policy' died
06-20 13:36:07.069: I/ServiceManager(3046): service 'remoteinjection' died
...
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Android crash"? Can you paste the LOGCAT?